# Initializing a char* value within struct within a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have been looking online but so far nothing has helped me understand my problem. Currently I am trying to make two lists that each contain a list of words. Each space contains a word struct and within each word struct is list of 30 doc_list structs. I have been able to allocate memory and store a char*s within the word list struct but when I try to allocate memory and store a char* within a doc_list struct I get a segmentation error. I am confused because I declared my doc_list struct the same exact way as I did my word_list struct.

Below is the initialization of my structs

In my C file I initialize my Hash Table

```
#define BUFFSIZE 1000
#define STOPLIST_INDEX 0
#define DOCUMENTS_INDEX 1

struct HashTable{
    int tableSize;
    struct word_list** wordList;
};

struct word_list{
    char* word;
    struct doc_list** docList;
};

struct doc_list{
   char* docName;
   int timesAppear;
};
//Initialing lists associated with hash table
struct HashTable** initialize_hash_table(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int k; //HashTables
    int i; //Words
    int q; //Document names
    struct HashTable** hashTable = calloc(2, sizeof(struct HashTable **));
    for(k =0; k < 2; k++)
    {
     hashTable[k] =  calloc (1, sizeof(struct HashTable *)); 
     hashTable[k]->wordList =  calloc(BUFFSIZE, sizeof(struct word_list **));

     for(i = 0; i < BUFFSIZE; i++)
     {
         hashTable[k]->wordList[i] =  calloc(1, sizeof(struct word_list *)); 
         hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList =  calloc(30, sizeof(struct doc_list**));
         for(q = 0; q < 30; q++)
         {
             hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList[q] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct doc_list*));
         }
     }
   } 


  return hashTable;
}
```

then in my insert function where I store the document name char* value is where I get a segmentation error. I don't understand why this happens because I initialized my doc_list structure the exact same way that I initialized my word_list structure.

```
int insert(struct HashTable** hashTable, char* document_word, char* filename, int index)
{
    //create the hash key
    int key = hashFunction(document_word, BUFFSIZE);
    //Check if word exists in Stop List
    if(index == 0 || hashTable[STOPLIST_INDEX]->wordList[key]->word == NULL)
    {
        //insert into list
        hashTable[index]->wordList[key] = malloc(sizeof(struct word_list*));
        hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->word = strdup(document_word);
        printf("%s%s\n", "INSERTED VALUE: ", hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->word);
        //Add filename to words' document list

         int w = 0;
         puts("segfaulting here");
         puts("1");
         hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->docList[w] = malloc(sizeof(struct doc_list*));
         hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->docList[w]->docName = strdup(filename);
         printf("%s%s\n", "INSERTED ", filename);
         printf("\n"); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

What I believe is happening is that all the word structs are being declared NULL if they are not allocated memory for a word but none of the doc_list structs are being declared NULL for some reason. I allocated memory for them the exact same way I did the word_list structs.

The output when I run the program is this:

```
Hashing filename:stopwords.txt
---------
INSERTED VALUE: a
segfaulting here
1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: you can simplify your code quite a bit if you change your `struct` definition to use one level pointers instead of two level pointers. For instance, you can use `struct HashTable{ int tableSize; struct word_list* wordList; };`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

```
 hashTable[k] =  calloc (1, sizeof(struct HashTable *));
```

needs to be changed to

```
 hashTable[k] =  calloc (1, sizeof(struct HashTable));
```

Type of `hasTable[k]` is `struct HashTable*`. The object that it points to has to be of size `struct HashTable`, not `struct HashTable*`.

There is a similar error in:

```
struct HashTable** hashTable = calloc(2, sizeof(struct HashTable **));
```

It needs to be:

```
struct HashTable** hashTable = calloc(2, sizeof(struct HashTable*));
```

You won't see the error easily since `sizeof(struct HashTable*)` is equal to `sizeof(struct HashTable**)` in most cases.

More of such errors are in `initialize_hash_table`.

```
hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList =  calloc(30, sizeof(struct doc_list**));
```

needs to be

```
hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList =  calloc(30, sizeof(struct doc_list*));

hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList[q] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct doc_list*));
```

needs to be

```
hashTable[k]->wordList[i]->docList[q] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct doc_list));
```

You have similar errors in `insert`.

```
hashTable[index]->wordList[key] = malloc(sizeof(struct word_list*));
```

needs to be

```
hashTable[index]->wordList[key] = malloc(sizeof(struct word_list));

hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->docList[w] = malloc(sizeof(struct doc_list*));
```

needs to be

```
hashTable[index]->wordList[key]->docList[w] = malloc(sizeof(struct doc_list));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Only use `calloc` if you actually need your memory zeroed. `malloc` is faster.
Also, there is no need to test unequality to `0` `NULL` `\0`, unless you need your truth value normalized to `0`|`1`, and even then `!!` is preferrable. `!` for equality to 0 in any of its guises.

But your real problem is something else:

```
struct HashTable** hashTable = calloc(2, sizeof(struct HashTable **));
```

The above line alloates zeroed memory for 2 `struct HashTable**`, and stores the pointer in `hashTable`, which has type `sttruct HashTable**` too!!
You actually want to allocate space for 2 `struct HashTable*`.

In this one specific case it does not kill you, because those two pointer types happen to use the same amount of space on this architecture, but it's a pattern which is repeated with worse results later, and allocating too little memory leads to buffer overruns, which as **Undefined Behavior** mean anything can happen (and naturally mostly bad things).

When you want to point with pointer p to a memory block, allocate it thus:

```
p = malloc(count * sizeof *p);
p = calloc(count, sizeof *p); /* only for zeroed memory */
```

You do not want to use `sizeof` on the type, because it is far too easy to get it wrong, adding or leaving off one or more levels of indirection or taking a completely unrelated type.
Unless you name a VLA to `sizeof`, it will *not* evaluate its arguments, but only get the type and derive a compile-ime-constant.

Some more things you should read:

- [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)
- [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
- [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)